# Identifying relations between Java classes for this UML Diagram?

Tags: java, object, interface, uml, diagram

I have this UML classes, but the relations are too confusing, is there a forum to try identifying relations like association, composition, etc.
Or even better, help me to identify them.
My professor thought it was a good idea not teaching this and making it part of a project months later.
Thanks in advance guys!!
[Here a pic of the classes in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPli9.png)

Answer (score 1):

I will not provide you the solution for your specific diagram. I'd rather provide some hints to help you solve these questions:

- For every interface, find the classes that expose all the operations of the interface with the exact same signature (operation name, return types, and parameters). These classes are excellent candidates for a realization relationship (doted line and hollow triangle pointing to the interface)
- For every property that has the type B in a class A, you have a potential association between A to B. The association end on B side would have a role name that matches the property name and the same multiplicity. Ideally you'd refactor the diagram removing the property from the class body, because it'll be redundant with the associatiin.
- then look for properties in one class that seem to refer to an id in the other class (same type, suggesting name,...). These are candidates for an association between the two classes, but analysis needs to confirm it because it's only a first guess
- for every operation in a class A that uses a parameter of type B or returns a type B, there is a dependency relationship from A to B. But don't show it if there's already an association. And don't show it if it clutters your diagram.